# JavaFX projects

Tags: java, open-source, javafx

Are there any JavaFX projects (e.g. games) available as open source? Maybe a (JavaFX) counterpart to (C#) CodeProject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at Kenai:

- http://kenai.com/projects_tags/javafx

or Google Code:

- http://code.google.com/query/#q=javafx

or SourceForge:

- http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=javafx

Comment: Here is a repo on github related to JavaFX that can help you for building the foundation on JavaFX https://github.com/enriquezrene/curso-javafx-udemy

Comment: most of the links are dead!!